# How to work with Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I want to know how to work with `Java 8` streams and how to use the different kind of available stream operations.
For example, I wrote this part of code:

```
ArrayList<State> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
for (State s : newStates)
     if (path.contains(s))     // path is a stack of State
         toBeRemoved.add(s);
for (State s : toBeRemoved)
     newStates.remove(s);
```

I want to rewrite it using `java 8 stream api calls`. How can I do it?

Comment: Streams work best on immutable data structures (or data structures you *treat* as immutable, to be more precise).  If you're trying to modify an existing data structure, like you are here with `newStates`, you probably don't want to use streams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for a stream here, you can use [the new `Collection#removeIf` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
newStates.removeIf(path::contains);
```

Or, if `path` is a `Collection`:

```
newStates.removeAll(path);
```

Comment: `newStates.removeAll(path);`…

Comment: @Holger yes indeed ;-) I hadn't noticed that path was (probably) a Collection.

Comment: I am surprise that they add this `removeIf` default method. It looks very specific.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you can simply produce an output List containing only the States that should be retained, and assign that List to the `newStates` variable :

```
newStates = newStates.stream()
                     .filter(s -> !path.contains(s))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The filter keeps only States for which `path.contains(s)` returns false.

Of course, if `newStates` is originally initialized as a copy of some "oldStates" List, you can skip that initilization step and use the original "oldStates" List as input.

Comment: Thank you. That works, but I need to know how to use this api. Please write a simple toturial or something. Not just this case. Thank you.

Comment: @Rasoolll  `Please write a simple toturial`. I don't think so. How about Googling "Java 8 Streams tutorial"?

Comment: Tried that. found nothing good. For now, I up-voted your answer. I'll wait for a couple of hours, if no one answered better than you, then your answer will be accepted. Thanks again buddy. :)

Comment: @Rasoolll So you Googled "Java 8 Streams" and found nothing good? There are dozens of awesome posts and articles on that topic. Oracle has their Java Tutorial on the subject. The API documentation on the streams package is incredibly good, not to mention an increasing number of awesome books on the subject. I'd say the help you need is on refining your investigation skills.

Comment: tutorials are alright if you are experienced,  there are awesome books around to help you from the scratch...

Comment: Also, check out the documentation on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/88/streams#t=201611150829313141085